# Error 404--Not Found The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI

Tags: java

I am getting below error while executing the code

```
Error 404--Not Found

From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:

10.4.5 404 Not Found
```

The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent.

If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code `403` (Forbidden) can be used instead.

The `410` (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address.

As I can see  URI is correct and still getting the above mentioned error.

Comment: Could you please provide more  information about the code which you are executing?

Comment: "I am getting below error while executing the code"...  which code are you trying to execute?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]